# Getting "java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet" in Eclipse + jboss 5.1.0

Tags: eclipse, jboss5.x, resteasy

I'm trying to get a simple RestEasy project to work in Eclipse (with Jboss Tools) and Jboss 5.1.0. To get going, I've created a simple Dynamic Web Project. In the project, I've include the following in WEB-INF/web.xml:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>resteasy.scan</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ResteasyBootstrap</listener-class>
</listener>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Resteasy</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Resteasy</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

On trying to start the above project (in Jboss running in Eclipse), I get the following exception in the Console:

```
14:10:17,614 ERROR [AbstractKernelController] Error installing to Real: name=vfsfile:/Users/groove/Documents/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.jboss.ide.eclipse.as.core/JBoss_5.1_Runtime_Server1326046666357/deploy/blankWeb.war/ state=PreReal mode=Manual requiredState=Real
org.jboss.deployers.spi.DeploymentException: Error during deploy: vfsfile:/Users/groove/Documents/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.jboss.ide.eclipse.as.core/JBoss_5.1_Runtime_Server1326046666357/deploy/blankWeb.war/
at org.jboss.deployers.spi.DeploymentException.rethrowAsDeploymentException(DeploymentException.java:49)
at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployerWrapper.deploy(DeployerWrapper.java:185)
at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doDeploy(DeployersImpl.java:1454)
at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doInstallParentFirst(DeployersImpl.java:1172)
at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.install(DeployersImpl.java:1113)
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContext.install(AbstractControllerContext.java:348)
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:1652)
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.incrementState(AbstractController.java:938)
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1082)
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:988)
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:826)
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:556)
at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.process(DeployersImpl.java:789)
at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.main.MainDeployerImpl.process(MainDeployerImpl.java:699)
at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.MainDeployerAdapter.process(MainDeployerAdapter.java:117)
at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.hotdeploy.HDScanner.scan(HDScanner.java:409)
at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.hotdeploy.HDScanner.run(HDScanner.java:294)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:441)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRunAndReset(FutureTask.java:317)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:150)
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$101(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:98)
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.runPeriodic(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:204)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/http/HttpServlet
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:631)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:615)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:283)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:58)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:197)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:295)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:247)
at org.jboss.classloader.plugins.loader.ClassLoaderToLoaderAdapter.loadClass(ClassLoaderToLoaderAdapter.java:188)
at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.ClassLoadingTask$ThreadTask.run(ClassLoadingTask.java:455)
at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.ClassLoaderManager.nextTask(ClassLoaderManager.java:267)
at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.ClassLoaderManager.process(ClassLoaderManager.java:166)
at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseClassLoaderDomain.loadClass(BaseClassLoaderDomain.java:276)
at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseClassLoaderDomain.loadClass(BaseClassLoaderDomain.java:1138)
at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseClassLoader.loadClassFromDomain(BaseClassLoader.java:862)
at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseClassLoader.doLoadClass(BaseClassLoader.java:502)
at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseClassLoader.loadClass(BaseClassLoader.java:447)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
at org.jboss.webservices.integration.util.ASHelper.getEndpointClass(ASHelper.java:295)
at org.jboss.webservices.integration.util.ASHelper.getWebServiceServlets(ASHelper.java:398)
at org.jboss.webservices.integration.util.ASHelper.getJaxwsServlets(ASHelper.java:194)
at org.jboss.webservices.integration.deployers.WSTypeDeployer.isJaxwsJseDeployment(WSTypeDeployer.java:153)
at org.jboss.webservices.integration.deployers.WSTypeDeployer.internalDeploy(WSTypeDeployer.java:68)
at org.jboss.deployers.spi.deployer.helpers.AbstractRealDeployer.deploy(AbstractRealDeployer.java:55)
at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployerWrapper.deploy(DeployerWrapper.java:179)
... 24 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
... 56 more
14:10:17,632 WARN  [HDScanner] Failed to process changes
org.jboss.deployers.client.spi.IncompleteDeploymentException: Summary of incomplete deployments (SEE PREVIOUS ERRORS FOR DETAILS):

*** DEPLOYMENTS IN ERROR: Name -> Error

vfsfile:/Users/groove/Documents/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.jboss.ide.eclipse.as.core/JBoss_5.1_Runtime_Server1326046666357/deploy/blankWeb.war/ -> org.jboss.deployers.spi.DeploymentException: Error during deploy: vfsfile:/Users/gnarula1/Documents/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.jboss.ide.eclipse.as.core/JBoss_5.1_Runtime_Server1326046666357/deploy/blankWeb.war/


DEPLOYMENTS IN ERROR:
Deployment "vfsfile:/Users/groove/Documents/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.jboss.ide.eclipse.as.core/JBoss_5.1_Runtime_Server1326046666357/deploy/blankWeb.war/" is in error due to the following reason(s): java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet

at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.checkComplete(DeployersImpl.java:1008)
at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.checkComplete(DeployersImpl.java:954)
at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.main.MainDeployerImpl.checkComplete(MainDeployerImpl.java:870)
at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.MainDeployerAdapter.checkComplete(MainDeployerAdapter.java:128)
at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.hotdeploy.HDScanner.scan(HDScanner.java:416)
at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.hotdeploy.HDScanner.run(HDScanner.java:294)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:441)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRunAndReset(FutureTask.java:317)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:150)
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$101(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:98)
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.runPeriodic(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:204)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)
```

What could be causing this error ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of RestEasy is only supported out the box from version 6 of JBoss IIRC.

Heres a link to the rest easy website if you do need to download it.
http://www.jboss.org/resteasy

> 1. I make the assumption that you allready have a
>      **Preferences>Server>Runtime Environment>** configured for JBoss. If not do that first.
> 2. **Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/http/HttpServlet.** This tells me that if you got 1
>      above right you have not added it to your buildpath yet as
>      **Properties>Java Build Path>Add Library>Server Runtime.** The runtime contains the servletapi.
> 3. **org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ResteasyBootstrap** lives in the **resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.0.GA.jar** jar. Dump it in your
>      WEB_INF/lib folder. DO NOT add it to your build path via Eclipse.
>      Eclipse takes care of that it self.
> 4. **org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.** Same as 3 above.
> 5. `<param-name>resteasy.scan</param-name>` This functionality I believe is a runtime dependency and lives in the
>      **scannotation-1.0.3.jar**. Dump it in WEB_INF/lib. Again, Eclipse takes care of the classpath.
> 6. This is after all a JAX-RS project so dump **jaxrs-api-2.3.0.GA.jar** to your in WEB_INF/lib. This will bring in the **@Path, @Get, etc** annotations for use in your resource classes.
> 7. I also have **jaxb-api-2.2.3.jar**, **javassist-3.8.0.GA.jar** and **jackson-jaxrs-1.8.5.jar** in my WEB-INF/lib but from here on out it depends what functionality you are going to use and which providers
>      loggers etc.

---

I hope I nailed the essentials jars, if anyone spots a missing one please correct. My first try at JAX-RS I just dumped the whole shebang of 56 jars in WEB-INF/lib (Not a good idea)

Have Fun!!